# Search and replace part of string

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know how to replace the a part of a value which is stored into a columns named "keyword_data" in the table "keyword".

The values in the MySQL columns look like this:

```
a:5:{s:11:"{%KEYWORD%}";s:59:"keyword test 1";s:9:"{%PRICE%}";s:6:"279,99";s:12:"{%CATEGORY%}";s:6:"Camera";s:9:"{%IMAGE%}";s:61:"http://exemple.com/images/I/1172oJo2lpL._AA160_.jpg";s:12:"{%REDIRECT%}";s:158:"http://www.exemple.net/keywordtest1/dp/B00EHK7QVK/ref=sr_1_750?s=hi&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1428056859&amp;sr=1-750&amp;keywords=hd1?tag=mytag";}

a:5:{s:11:"{%KEYWORD%}";s:53:"keyword test 2";s:9:"{%PRICE%}";s:6:"397,61";s:12:"{%CATEGORY%}";s:3:"cat";s:9:"{%IMAGE%}";s:61:"exemple.com/images/I/21iYVLu80SL._AA160_.jpg";s:12:"{%REDIRECT%}";s:187:"exemple.com/keywordtest2/dp/B00RDF1GLW/ref=sr_1_6064?s=industrial&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1428944582&amp;sr=1-6064&amp;keywords=hd2?tag=mytag";}
```

etc.

I cannot just make a simple replace value since they are all different.

Each row has a different keyword, I only need to replace this for each row in the table.

```
 ?tag=mytag
```

into

```
 &tag=mytag
```

Any help from the community would be cool :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
  UPDATE keyword SET keyword_data = REPLACE( keyword_data , '?tag=mytag' , '&tag=mytag') 
         WHERE keyword_data LIKE '%?tag=mytag%';
```

[Working example!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26e1d/1)

Also you should be really careful with this. Always make a copy of your database before you fool around with it like that since you can easily mess everything up just because you missed a little char somewhere.

Comment: thx you very much deW1 this syntax work prefectly you rock (also Erasmus was near)  all the best to you (i cant vote due to my low reputation)

Comment: @ivandelaware you accept answers by clicking the green tick on the left below the voting to show other people what answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

mysql provides a command called REPLACE.

REPLACE has the following structure:

```
 REPLACE(text, from_string, to_string)
```

This can be used in an update statement:

```
    UPDATE keyword SET keyword_data = REPLACE(keyword_data, '?tag=mytag', '&tag=mytag');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use REPLACE()  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

```
SELECT REPLACE('?tag=mytag','?','&');
->&tag=mytag
```